# How to give user rights to Sitecore Experience Analytics Dashboard sites dropdown/Site analytics

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-analytics

[image: Sitecore Experience Analytics Dashboard filter a report by website]

I want to give user rights per user per website. for example UserA can only see www.jumpintotravel.dk analytics same way UserB can only see www.jumpintotravel.net only.

How to give user rights to particular site only?

Comment: Typically such lists come from a list of items, and you will need to set permissions for the source items. But here it looks like you will need to override some kind of data provider and check permissions in code.

Comment: We have similar requirement for our website. Did you manage to solve this?. It will be great if you can share some details to achieve this. Thanks,
Indra